# Gluing two disks to get an exotic sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, spheres, manifolds-with-boundary

I have found interest in the subject of exotic spheres. Particularly, the 7-sphere. To create such a sphere, you glue two copies $\mathbb{D}^4\times \mathbb{S}^3$ along the boundary identifying $(u,v)$ with $(u,u^hvu^j)$ such that $h+j=\pm1$.

Now my question is, the fact that I am trying to construct such a sphere by gluing two 7-disks along the boundary via a diffeomorphism. However, it seems I cannot find such a diffeomorphism explicitly. By diffeomorphism I mean the map $h:\partial \mathbb{S}^6\to\partial \mathbb{S}^6$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you really wanna do it, you would have to go back to Milnor's original paper, take the explicit Morse function he gives on the exotic $7$-sphere and solve for its gradient flow in coordinates. I don't see any reason to expect that an explicit solution of the resulting differential equation is feasible (though I will also admit I have not written it down.)